# Как остановить выполнение цикла for?

Tags: c#

Допустим, для примера, есть простой цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Как сделать, чтобы когда цикл дошел до какого-либо значения, например 20 `(if (i==20)`, мы бы из него вышли?

Comment: Стоп, а дальше что?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper ничего, просто стоп и все, он дальше не идет

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <=20; i++)`

Comment: @Ev_Hyper и так знаю что так можно, думаю, мб break юзать

Answer (score 11):

Если условие самого цикла не хотите изменять, то добавьте в тело цикла условную конструкцию, при выполнении которой будет происходить выход из цикла с помощью [break](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/adbctzc4.aspx):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    if(i == 20) break;
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

В противном же случае делайте, как вам предложил в комментариях @Ev_Hyper:

```
for (int i = 0; i <=20; i++)
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно так:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    if(i == 20) i=31;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте после if оператор break. Оператор break завершает действие в котором он находится.  Или можно просто в самом цикле for указать 20 а не 30. Цикл for уже заранее позволяет, указать цикл и дать знать где ему остановить своё действие.